# Set value of speed slider programmatically

Tags: netlogo

In `setup`, I draw a bunch of turtles--as small circles--to display two curves defined by functions.  A very simple way to do this is

```
ask patches with [pycor = (myfunction pxcor)] [sprout 1 [...]]
```

and that's what my code does at present.  It's kind of wasteful, since every patch has to be consulted--in random order--for each curve, but it's simple and easy to read, and it only happens during setup.

However, there's a little bit of a pause as the curves are constructed.  If I move the speed slider all the way to the right, the pause is not noticeable.  If I wrap the curve display routines in `no-display` and `display`, the user doesn't see the curves being constructed, but the speed is unchanged, AFAICS.  If I move the slider to the left, it takes a long time to construct the curves even with `no-display`; the user doesn't see the points being placed one by one, but nevertheless has to wait while twiddling her/his thumbs.

Is there a way to set the model speed programmatically (for normal, "headfull" use)?  I don't want to tell users "Move the speed slider to the right, then press `setup`, then move it back to the center before pressing `go`.

If not, maybe I'll code the curves properly using loops, but I thought I'd ask.   Seems like there would be a way to do this, but I haven't found anything in the dictionary or programming docs so far.

(edit: `no-display`, if it did help, isn't available in NetLogo Web, which I am targetting along with regular NetLogo.)

Comment: Are you using tick-based updates?

Comment: There is now quite a bit of discussion on this over at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1602

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is. However, you are asking all patches, when you could simply ask the pxcor values. This should speed it up a lot - square root of the number of iterations if a square world. Something like:

```
to testme
  clear-all
  let counter min-pxcor
  while [counter <= max-pxcor]
  [ let fn-out (function counter)
    if fn-out >= min-pycor and fn-out <= max-pycor
    [ ask patch counter fn-out [ set pcolor red]
    ]
    set counter counter + 1
  ]
end

to-report function [#invalue]
  report #invalue ^ 2
end
```

Comment: Thanks JenB.  Yes, that's roughly what I had in mind for a loop solution.  Not truly complicated, but compared to a one-line "ask patches ...", it's a shame, since the only reason that it's slow is an unnecessary delay between steps.

Comment: I'm surprised that `no-display` didn't fix it.The transition guide for v6 has a brief discussion of frame rates in the heading 'Model Speed' that might give you some ideas.

Comment: Yeah, surprised me, too.  Thanks--the frame rate discussion is interesting, though I don't see a good solution there; `every` doesn't seem to be the best option.  Rewriting the function plots as loops was better anyway, because even at top speed NetLogo Web was taking a long time with the simple `ask patches` version.